# Read Text File With HTML

Tags: php, html, file, variables

I was wondering if there is a way to read the ALL of the contents of a file and store it in a variable in HTML.

By using PHP with HTML, I get some unworking code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <?php echo "Current Prodi-G version: " . file_get_contents('/version.txt');?>;
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code gets rendered in the parsing and displaying of the web page, but only a `;` appears...

Comment: [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) does what you asked for. But you should elaborate your use case. What do you mean by combining?

Comment: Need more background on what you are trying to achieve here. You can read files using PHP, however HTML does not really have any concept of variables so you will need to explain what you are trying to do. Are you trying to just show the contents of a file in a textarea or something?

Comment: @micha Everybody has to start somewhere. If you're going to tell them to go away, at least give them somewhere else to go.

Comment: @JavaCoder-1337 The contents of script tags do not get rendered. Make sure you check the source of the document once it's loaded in the browser (all browsers let you do this, right-click "view page source" or similar). If you see the contents of version.txt anywhere in there, you're on the right track, you just need to move it into the body tag so that it will be rendered. And if you don't understand what I just described above, you need to spend more time learning the fundamentals, as I described in my answer below.

Comment: When I do this, the source shows up with the script tags, but nothing is displayed ... What am I doing wrong?!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML is not a programming language. It's a markup language. It simply describes how things should look and be laid out on a webpage.

PHP is a programming language, not a markup language. It performs logic and is able to process files and other things.

You'll need both, combined, to do what you'd like. And there are plenty of good HTML+PHP tutorials out there to help you. Search google and here for that.

This will get you each line in file: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-readfiles/

After that, it's up to you to format and parse it how you want. I suggest spending some time on php.net (http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php) or searching google for information. Someone has done what you want, I'm almost positive.

EDIT:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            <?php echo "Current version: " . file_get_contents('/version.txt');?>;
        </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

This doesn't work because it tells PHP to put what ever the contents of version.txt is into the script tags of the page, or more importantly, to put it exactly where you're calling the PHP code from.

For it to be displayed, the content that PHP generates in the `<?php ?>` areas of the code has to be inside of HTML tags that will eventually display.

For instance:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <?php echo "Current version: " . file_get_contents('/version.txt');?>;
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Because the HTML tag `<script></script>` is supposed to contain ***invisible*** javascript code, whereas the `<div></div>` is a generic tag meant to hold ***visible*** content. Your example doesn't work because it's putting all of that output in the invisible parts of the page instead of the visible ones.

Comment: @JavaCoder-1337 We've attempted to answer your question. And given you the correct one. We're at a crossroads where your inexperience with the technology you're trying to use is getting in the way of us being able to help. You need to follow the links in my post above, and spend some time on the internet running through tutorials on HTML, PHP and how they interoperate before anything we've discussed can truly be helpful. But that's OK. Learning is always good, and once you're all up to speed on the subject at hand, come back and this will all make much more sense.

Answer (score 4):

In php this is easy...

```
<?php
    $filename = fopen('document_name', 'r'); 
    $file = fread($filename, filesize('document_name'));
    echo $file; 
    fclose($filename);
?>
```

Is this what you are looking for?

You can also use file_get_contents() which is even easier for this...

**EDIT**

After reviewing your edit, if you are simply trying to output the "version" to the screen this is what your file should look like...

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php echo 'Current version: ' . file_get_contents('/version.txt'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Using the script tag tells the browser that you are going to use client side scripting aka. Javascript. In turn you cannot simply "echo" out a statement to the screen. Don't get me wrong though a javascript application to can be used like this to do it...

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var text = <?php echo 'Current version: ' . file_get_contents('/version.txt'); ?>;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        document.write(text);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

...but this is kind of overkill unless you need to store the value inside a javascript variable. To solve what seems to be the confusion inside your mind, PHP scripting is completely seperate from Javascript scripting (although they can be used together) and must by used as separate entities, even though they can both be used anywhere within a document.

Comment: I am aware of how to do it with PHP. I need to know how to find it by USING PHP with HTML.

Comment: by looking at your edit, you just need to remove the script tags as well as the semicolon after the closing ?>. Then it should work...

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if you were referring to something like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var html = "<?php echo file_get_contents('/tmp/somefile.dat');?>";
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Sample</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @JavaCoder-1337 What do mean by *doesn't work*?  You'll have to tweak what I gave you to suit your need.  Btw, I have no idea what you wanted to do, frankly, and I don't understand what you mean by **a variable in HTML**.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php echo 'Current version: ' . file_get_contents('/version.txt'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

is the correct solution for your question. What may not have been clear is that you must save the file as a '.php' file, not an '.html' file.

So, to get this example to work, you would have to name the file something like: `version.php` (You described your problem as your web page only displayed the semicolon) which would have been the case if you named your file `version.html` and you had the misplaced semicolon after the closing php tag.

Correct:`?>`
Wrong: `?>;`

Comment: Most servers can process html as php - you just have to add a line in the .htaccess (or equivalent)

Comment: It is highly recommended that you never allow HTML pages to automatically handle PHP or SHTML because this forces all of your HTML pages to be processed by the server first. Instead, please rename your files to .php or .shtml whenever possible.